# Asynchronous Logger integration with Spring

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j, log4j2

I want to implement asynchronous logger in my Spring web application. Now after searching over the net, I came to know, the following 3 ways can be used to achieve this.

1. commons.log4j
2. log4j2
3. @Async in spring.
   (I know there are other ways too, but I want to stick to either of these 3)

Now I want to know which one would be the best to use with a better performance?
Would asynchronous logging with commons.log4j have a lot of drawbacks?

It would be great if anyone can come up with documentations.

Answer (score 0):

Log4j2 has asynchronous loggers based on the LMAX Disruptor. This is essentially a lock-free queue which gives large performance benefits compared to other logging libraries. See [recent benchmark results here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/performance.html).

On top of that Log4j2 is garbage-free which means it will not add pressure on the garbage collector. As a result your application temporarily objects won't get promoted to old gen as fast which means fewer full gc pauses. But that's just a nice to have.

For your logging facade, Commons Logging is generally considered legacy technology and there are several reasons to avoid it. SLF4J seems to be popular but there is nothing wrong with simply using the Log4j2 API (it actually has a separate log4j-api module unlike Log4j 1.2).

Spring @Async is not intended for asynchronous logging. It is better suited for more coarse grained tasks you want to execute on a background thread. Going through Spring 's TaskExecutor for each logging statement will likely overwhelm the executor queue (not lock-free as far as I know). Also it may result in hard to read code.

Comment: https://spring.io/blog/2009/12/04/logging-dependencies-in-spring/
Unfortunately, the worst thing about commons-logging, and what has made it unpopular with new tools, is also the runtime discovery algorithm. If we could turn back the clock and start Spring now as a new project it would use a different logging dependency. Probably the first choice would be the Simple Logging Facade for Java (SLF4J), which is also used by a lot of other tools that people use with Spring inside their applications.